# Odata v.4 compression support in UWP Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: compression, odata, uwp

Our application needs to transfer a significant amount of data through  Odata v4 service. We enabled data compression in server-side, for the client we use an UWP application on Windows 10 Mobile for ARM devices (build 10586.29). The client code is as follows:

```
HttpClient http = new HttpClient(new ClientCompressionHandler(new GZipCompressor(), new DeflateCompressor()));
http.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
http.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));
```

Unfortunately, seems that Microsoft.AspNet.Webapi.MessageHandlers.Compression
 needs System.Web.Http.dll, which cannot be resolved when building the application ("Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file: 'System.Web.Http.dll').

Is there *any* way to achieve compression support in client-side using UWP Windows Mobile 10 for ARM?

Comment: What package contains `ClientCompressionHandler`?

Comment: You may check this nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.MessageHandlers.Compression/

Comment: I am not sure, but it looks like a package problem, can you try one version earlier? `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.MessageHandlers.Compression -Version 1.2.2`

Comment: Notice the author of the package is not Microsoft, and the author has GitHub repo: https://github.com/azzlack/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.MessageHandlers.Compression